# How to generate dynamic values for a json request in Soap UI for load test

Tags: json, groovy, soapui, soap-client

I have a Json Request Similar to below request.

`{"age": {
            "description": "Age in years",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": "1"
        },
        "details":{
       "name":"John",
       "age":"30",
       "cars":"BMW"
        }}`

In Name field it should select only three selected Names (ex: John,Jim,James). In the age and Cars fields it should dynamically change the values. I tried in Java i am able to do. I am trying to do in SoapUi, can any one help me in SoapUi

Comment: the above json is not valid. was there any change that you made?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate JSON object dynamically (or randomly) you can try following approach:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def names = ['John', 'Jim', 'James']
def cars = ['BMW', 'Toyota', 'Ford', 'Honda']
def ages = 18..50

def random = new Random()

def obj = [
        name: names.get(random.nextInt(names.size())),
        age: ages.get(random.nextInt(ages.size())),
        car: cars.get(random.nextInt(cars.size()))
]

def json = new JsonOutput().toJson(obj)
```

What happens here is we define a list of names, cars and ages, and then we pick randomly one element of each list and build a final object. Lastly we use `JsonOutput.toJson()` method to marshal the object (which is a `Map<String,Object>` type in this case) to a `String`.

Running this script couple of times and printing `json` variable will produce an output similar to this one:

```
{"name":"John","age":40,"car":"Toyota"}
{"name":"James","age":28,"car":"Honda"}
{"name":"James","age":26,"car":"Ford"}
{"name":"Jim","age":32,"car":"Honda"}
```

Of course this is just an example that shows general use case. I couldn't create a final JSON you expect since the example you have posted is not a valid JSON object. I guess you can apply this example to your specific use case and build a final JSON that meets all your expectations.